# Split large file into smaller files by number of lines in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am trying to figure out how to split a file by the number of lines in each file. THe files are csv and I can't do it by bytes. I need to do it by lines. 20k seems to be a good number per file. What is the best way to read a stream at a given position? Stream.BaseStream.Position? So if I read the first 20k lines i would start the position at 39,999? How do I know I am almost at the end of a files? Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried 20k calls to ReadLine?

Comment: You shouldn't need to seek at all.  You should read it line by line, switching to a new file once you hit 20k.

Comment: Yeah, after I wrote this and went to get my hair cut. It dawned on me that I can jsut read it unitl the end and do a readline. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("path"))
{
    int fileNumber = 0;

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        int count = 0;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("other path" + ++fileNumber))
        {
            sw.AutoFlush = true;

            while (!sr.EndOfStream && ++count < 20000)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems the most straight forward to me, though for memory's sake I would flush the write buffer with each write possibly. if each line is 100 bytes, that makes 1000 lines 100k, and 20000 2Mb, not a ton of memory but an unnecesarry foot print..

Comment: @Jimmy - I added `AutoFlush = True`, which automatically flushes after each write.

Comment: AutoFlush is a bad idea on a StreamWriter as it will flush after every single character (I looked at the code). If you don't specify a buffer size when creating a StreamWriter it defaults to only 128 characters, but that's still better than no buffer at all.

Answer (score 5):

```
int index=0;
var groups = from line in File.ReadLines("myfile.csv")
             group line by index++/20000 into g
             select g.AsEnumerable();
int file=0;
foreach (var group in groups)
        File.WriteAllLines((file++).ToString(), group.ToArray());
```

Comment: You need to use `File.ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` -- `ReadAllLines` reads it all into memory at once.  Also, using `index` in the grouping function like that freaks me out.

Comment: While this is indeed interesting, there are enough cases that you don't want to read an entire file into memory that I would at least add the stipulation that you need to know the files won't be too large if you're going to use this method..

Comment: Won't the grouping method collect everything regardless of whether you use ReadLines or ReadAllLines?

Comment: I assume so, but with `ReadAllLines`, you'd have the whole thing in memory twice instead of once.

Comment: Never thought about using LINQ. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
// helper method to break up into blocks lazily

public static IEnumerable<ICollection<T>> SplitEnumerable<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> Sequence, int NbrPerBlock)
{
    List<T> Group = new List<T>(NbrPerBlock);

    foreach (T value in Sequence)
    {
        Group.Add(value);

        if (Group.Count == NbrPerBlock)
        {
            yield return Group;
            Group = new List<T>(NbrPerBlock);
        }
    }

    if (Group.Any()) yield return Group; // flush out any remaining
}

// now it's trivial; if you want to make smaller files, just foreach
// over this and write out the lines in each block to a new file

public static IEnumerable<ICollection<string>> SplitFile(string filePath)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filePath).SplitEnumerable(20000);
}
```

Is that not sufficient for you?  You mention moving from position to position,but I don't see why that's necessary.