# Writing to .csv - limit max size by row and automatically create new files

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing into a .csv file from multiple dictionaries. I want to limit the max size of this output file by 10,000 rows and create new files to print next lines.
The following code is writing to the file `OutputFile`. If say, the output file has 60,000 rows, then instead of printing 60,000 rows in a single file, I want 10,000 rows to be printed in one file and rest of the lines in other files. So, I Will have 6 outputFiles with 10K rows in each file.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OutputPath + "OutputFile-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yy_hh.mm.ss.tt") + ".csv"))
{
    foreach (var program in _Code1)     
    {
        string Id = program.ToString();
        foreach (var entry in _List1)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Value.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                string LineValue = entry.Value.ToString();
                string[] SplitedLine = LineValue.Split(',');

                string query = "\"Insert into table(Id,UserID) values('" + Id + "','" + SplitedLine[1] + "')\"";
                writer.WriteLine(query);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var program in _Code2)   
    {
        string Id = program.ToString();
        foreach (var entry in _List2)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Value.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                string LineValue = entry.Value.ToString();
                string[] SplitedLine = LineValue.Split(',');

                string query = "\"Insert into table(Id,UserID) values('" + Id + "','" + SplitedLine[2] + "')\"";
                writer.WriteLine(query);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var program in _Code1)  
    {
        string Id = program.ToString();
        foreach (var entry in _List3)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Value.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                string LineValue = entry.Value.ToString();
                string[] SplitedLine = LineValue.Split(',');

                string query = "Delete From table Where ID='" + Id + "' And UserID='" + SplitedLine[1] + "'";
                writer.WriteLine(query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked into this
[Split large file into smaller files by number of lines in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374040/split-large-file-into-smaller-files-by-number-of-lines-in-c)
But the solution here is writing from one file so it can count the number of rows but in my case I am writing from multiple dictionaries so how will I keep a tab of the max limit of the output file ?

Comment: You can count the lines and write to another file once you reach the limit

Comment: What are you trying to do though? This isn't a CSV file, it's a SQL script. Why are you writing `Insert into table(Id,UserID) values(`? to files? If you want to load data into a database, such a script is the slowest possible way to do it. All databases have a way to bulk import data from flat files or CSV files

Comment: 60K rows is almost no data. If you have size or performance issues, it's because os such INSERTs. Right now this code is wasting a lot of bytes repeating the same string, `Insert into table(Id,UserID) values(`. Importing is slow because this script has to execute 60K INSERTs one by one instead of using any of the fast import methods

Comment: Also, if this was SQL, which it actually looks like, a single INSERT can list any number of records, not just one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a requirement. To print these queries in .csv and in this way only. This is not something that I can change. and 10k lines per file is also a requirement. Not something that I can change.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This is a requirement. To print these inserts like this way only in .csv files. This is not something that I can change.

Comment: It's a bit difficult for us to interpret what your requirements are since a CSV is not the same as a SQL script.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError All I want is to split the output file that I am writing in the above code into multiple .csv if the number of rows exceeds 10k. For eg, for a 60k output lines, I should have 6 output file each of 10k. Now, my issue is that I have multiple dictionaries from which I am reading data. So, I am confused how should I analyze the number of rows and create new files for new lines.

Comment: This isn't a CSV, it's a SQL script. Please don't keep calling it a CSV and don't repeat the same wrong question. You're trying to create a SQL script. You can count the lines you generated in that loop and create a new file when you reach a specific limit. Have you tried that?

Comment: CSV means Comma Separated Values. It's a text file containing Values Separated by Commas, eg `Banana,123,2023-02-24`. Not INSERT commands.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know what a .csv file is. I am printing these queries in the same comma separated format. Why are you focusing on the data. That's not in my hand.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please check my answer below and let me know if there are better ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my issue. I counted every line after every insert in the above code. Then I checked if those lines were greater than 10k, if yes, then I opened the file that I had just written, read it, split its rows into multiple files, and deleted the original file. This is how I have done this. If there is any better than to achieve this then please let me know.

```
 if(ProgramMemberFileCount>10000)
                {
                    string path = OutputPath + filename + ".csv";
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
                    {
                        int fileNumber = 0;

                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            fileNumber++;
                            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter( OutputPath + fileNumber + filename + ".csv"))
                            {
                                sw.AutoFlush = true;

                                while (!sr.EndOfStream && ++count <= 10000)
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       
                    }

                    //System.GC.Collect();
                    //System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
```